# c++ new array with initialization I have never seen before in an interview

Tags: c++

What does the following code do?  I would guess that it instantiates an array of MyObjects, but I don't know?

```
new (p) [[MyObject]]
```

Comment: Looks like placement new but I have no idea what `[[ ]]` means.

Comment: Are you sure that is valid C++? And not some trick to test whether you have enough knowledge of C++ to be confident enough to call this wrong?

Comment: I've seen `[[x]]` used but not in this situation...

Comment: @cmaster: I am not sure if it was a trick or not, it was presented by an old school c++ guy.  I was told that it was a "bonus" interview question they have asked since 2004.

Comment: I just found the part in the standard about attributes (never heard about them before), so it was definitely not a trick, only a question to extremely obscure knowledge at that time...

Comment: Except that if they're been asking the question it couldn't be about the C++11 attributes feature except in the context of some pre-standard compiler-specific extension. As far as I know, C++11 style attributes were not a common extension. @xordon: any idea if they were asking about a particular toolchain?

Comment: This could have applied to many different compilers since they develop for many different platforms.  Perhaps one of the early network connected consoles.  Xbox, PS2, etc.

But I got the impression that it would have been common to all.

Comment: array indexing is essentially tmp[5] => *(tmp + 5), perhaps this is taking advantage of that?

Answer (score 6):

This code is certainly not a complete statement. I *could* imagine that the `[[MyObject]]` part is a user-define attribute applying to whatever is following this part of the expression. For example, the following code compiles:

```
#include <new>

int main()
{
    void* p = operator new(sizeof(int));
    new(p) [[MyObject]] int(17);
}
```

The `[[MyObject]]` part is using a user-defined attribute which is probably meaningless and I have actually no idea how it can be used (I should probably look at this at some point...). User-define attributes were introduced to C++11. See 7.6 [dcl.attr] for the relevant standardese.

Comment: When I use gcc 4.7.2, I cannot compile the same code. I get error "expected type-specifier before [ token" on line 2 of main function.

Comment: Are you refering to a C++14 feature?

Comment: @cppcoder: I haven't tried with gcc-4.7.2. I tried it with a relativly recent version of the gcc repository (gcc version 4.9.0 20131031) and, obviously, I specified `-std=c++11` (without that flag it won't work).

Comment: @cmaster: No. User defined attribute are part of C++11 (see 7.6 [dcl.attr]).